# Aginity Netezza macro containing a list

Tags: macros, netezza

I would like to put a list of names in my Aginity Netezza macro. For instance, I would like to be able to repeatedly use the list ("Adam", "Bill", "Cynthia", "Dick", "Ella", "Fanny") in my future queries, e.g. in WHERE clauses.

My questions are: 
(1) Is there a limit to how many characters I can put inside the "Value" window of the Query Parameters Editor? 
(2) Is there a way to make this work without using a macro? For instance, predefining this list somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the list into a (temporary) table, and simply join to it when necessasary:

```
Create temp table names as
Select ‘Adam’::varchar(50)
Union all Select ‘Bill’::varchar(50)
Union all Select ‘Cynthia’::varchar(50)
Union all Select ‘Dick’::varchar(50)
Union all Select ‘Ella’::varchar(50)
Union all Select ‘Fanny’
;
Select x.a,x.b 
from x 
where x.name in (select * from Names)
;
Select 
case 
    when x.name in (select * from Names) 
    then ‘Special’ 
    Else ‘Other’ 
End as NameGrp,
Count(*) as size,
Sum(income) as TotalIncome
Group by NameGrp
Order by size desc
;
```

Alternatively netezza has an extension toolkit that enables ARRAY data types, but especially the first query will not perform well if you use it for that purpose. Interested? See here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_array.html or google for examples

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.